# WPF app with transparent windows and remote desktop causing popunders

Tags: wpf, transparency, contextmenu, remote-desktop

I have a WPF application with AllowsTransparency="True" because we like funky borders.

When I remote desktop into a computer and run our application, menus and right click menus in textboxes are popping up behind the application. I verified this by making the background semi transparent. Here's a screen shot:

http://i662.photobucket.com/albums/uu345/jpchow26/popunder.png

We're using .net 3.5 SP1 on XP SP3. I've read some blogposts that this is supposed to fix some things with rendering but this is a bug for us.  Anyone know of any solutions or am I just out of luck on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug related to controls popping up behind their parent window discussed in [this MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/333d3d93-8837-42b3-a0ea-1a577485daed/).  There is a hotfix for XP mentioned in the article but some people still experience the issue after applying the hotfix.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use AllowsTransparency="True", it causes a lot of strange bugs and poor performance, if you want funky borders you should do it the old way - calling SetWindowRgn via interop.

Read http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx

look at the end at the section titled "Office 2007 without Aero – Or, you are responsible for everything".